# Communicating a successful workbox-background-sync replay to open clients

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm using React 17, Workbox 5, and react-scripts 4.
I created a react app with PWA template using:

npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa

I use BackgroundSyncPlugin from workbox-background-sync for my offline requests, so when the app is online again, request will be sent automatically.
The problem is I don't know when the request is sent in my React code, so I can update some states, and display a message to the user.

How can I communicate from the service worker to my React code that the request is sent and React should update the state?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a custom `onSync` callback when you configure `BackgroundSyncPlugin`. This code is then executed instead of Workbox's [built-in `replayRequests()` logic](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/79a415ceeac7fb8840762333f11c903152b74ac4/packages/workbox-background-sync/src/Queue.ts#L313-L342) whenever the criteria to retry the requests are met.

You can include whatever logic you'd like in this callback; `this.shiftRequest()` and `this.unshiftRequest(entry)` can be used to remove queued requests in order to retry them, and then re-add them if the retry fails. Here's an adaption of the default `replayRequests()` that will use `postMessage()` to communicate to all controlled `window` clients when a retry succeeds.

```js
async function postSuccessMessage(response) {
  const clients = await self.clients.matchAll();
  for (const client of clients) {
    // Customize this message format as you see fit.
    client.postMessage({
      type: 'REPLAY_SUCCESS',
      url: response.url,
    });
  }
}

async function customReplay() {
  let entry;
  while ((entry = await this.shiftRequest())) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(entry.request.clone());
      // Optional: check response.ok and throw if it's false if you
      // want to treat HTTP 4xx and 5xx responses as retriable errors.

      postSuccessMessage(response);
    } catch (error) {
      await this.unshiftRequest(entry);

      // Throwing an error tells the Background Sync API
      // that a retry is needed.
      throw new Error('Replaying failed.');
    }
  }
}

const bgSync = new BackgroundSyncPlugin('api-queue', {
  onSync: customReplay,
});

// Now add bgSync to a Strategy that's associated with
// a route you want to retry:
registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.pathname === '/api_endpoint',
  new NetworkOnly({plugins: [bgSync]}),
  'POST'
);
```

Within your client page, you can use [`navigator.seviceWorker.addEventListener('message', ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/message_event) to listen for incoming messages from the service worker and take appropriate action.